# C -- Trouble with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C, know some Java.
Trying to write a program that accepts 2D array that represents a directed adjacency matrix, and two numbers, scans the array and returns true if there is a directed path between them (top-down).

I am running into a problem with C implementation. Apparently I have to use pointers to values in array, whilst in Java I could've use values from array (compare, return to function, etc).

I'm pretty sure the logic is in place, I just need help with allocating '*'s in the right places and amounts.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 12

typedef int bool;
enum {false, true};

typedef struct adj_mat{
    int A [N][N];
}adj_mat;



int path(struct adj_mat A, int origin, int dest){
    int i;
    if (origin == dest) return true;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(A);i++){
        if (A[origin][i]){
            return path (A, i, dest);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof A` doesn't do what you think it does. Google it.

Comment: You need `sizeof A / sizeof *A` to get number of elements of `A`.

Comment: You should not typedef bool yourself. Use stdbool instead (and use C99 or C11 standard). And why use a typedef for the struct when using struct-domain name lateron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sizeof(A)
```

This probably does not give you what you expect. It is the number of bytes, not the number of elements.

```
A[origin][i]
```

Here you are trying to index the `struct adjmat` which doesn't work. You probably wanted to index the member `A`. Try:

```
A.A[origin][i]
```

It would probably be a good idea to rename `adj_mat A` to something else to avoid confusion.

You should also pass the address of `A` to the function and use `adj_mat*` as the argument type. If I understand correctly you want the recursion to operate on the same object.

Comment: Thank you. I have to use A for an assignment, I dislike it as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(A);i++){
```

This should be `for (i = 0; i < N; i++){`.

Also, your algorithm may not terminate since it didn't take care of cycles in graph.

Comment: Thank you. Feel so stupid, especially since I went out and declared it from the beginning. :)